# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with SharedPreference variable?

Tags: android, arrays, android-sharedpreferences

I have a simple application that prints jokes and saves your "favorite" ones. I am running into an arrayoutofbounds issue and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Android on 11/15/15.
 */
public class Pun extends Activity {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    public static final String TAG = Pun.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String mPath = "body.txt";
    public static final String mBusinessPath = "business.txt";
    public static final String mCrimePath = "crime.txt";
    public static final String mEducationPath = "education.txt";
    public static final String mEntertaintmentPath = "entertainment.txt";
    public static final String mFoodPath = "food.txt";
    public static final String mHealthPath = "health.txt";
    public static final String mNaturePath = "nature.txt";
    public static final String mPeoplePath = "people.txt";
    public static final String mPlacesPath = "places.txt";
    public static final String mTechnologyPath = "technology.txt";
    public static final String mTransportationPath = "transportation.txt";
    public static final String mWorkPath = "work.txt";
    private QuoteBank mQuoteBank;
    private List<String> mLines;
    private int counter = 0;

    private static int SIZE = 20;
    private String favorites1[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites2[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites3[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites4[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites5[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites6[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites7[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites8[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites9[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites10[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites11[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites12[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites13[] = new String[SIZE];

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pun);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9704824959875003/5950200773");

        mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Random r = new Random();
        final int i1 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;

        mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
        mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPath);

        textView.setText(mLines.get(i1));

        favorites1 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites2 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites3 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites4 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites5 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites6 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites7 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites8 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites9 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites10 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites11 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites12 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites13 = new String[SIZE];

        // Set all favorites1 to false for initial setup
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            favorites1[i] = "false";
            favorites2[i] = "false";
            favorites3[i] = "false";
            favorites4[i] = "false";
            favorites5[i] = "false";
            favorites6[i] = "false";
            favorites7[i] = "false";
            favorites8[i] = "false";
            favorites9[i] = "false";
            favorites10[i] = "false";
            favorites11[i] = "false";
            favorites12[i] = "false";
            favorites13[i] = "false";

        }

        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();

        // Save and Load array
        //saveArray(favorites1,"favorites1",this);
        favorites1 = loadArray("favorites1",this);
        favorites2 = loadArray("favorites2",this);
        favorites3 = loadArray("favorites3",this);
        favorites4 = loadArray("favorites4",this);
        favorites5 = loadArray("favorites5",this);
        favorites6 = loadArray("favorites6",this);
        favorites7 = loadArray("favorites7",this);
        favorites8 = loadArray("favorites8",this);
        favorites9 = loadArray("favorites9",this);
        favorites10 = loadArray("favorites10",this);
        favorites11 = loadArray("favorites11",this);
        favorites12 = loadArray("favorites12",this);
        favorites13 = loadArray("favorites13",this);

        final ImageButton favoritesBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        favoritesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (MainActivity.category){
                    case "body":
                        if(favorites1[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites1[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites1[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "crime":
                        if(favorites2[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites2[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites2[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "entertainment":
                        if(favorites3[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites3[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites3[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "health":
                        if(favorites4[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites4[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites4[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "people":
                        if(favorites5[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites5[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites5[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "technology":
                        if(favorites6[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites6[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites6[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "work":
                        if(favorites7[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites7[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites7[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "business":
                        if(favorites8[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites8[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites8[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "education":
                        if(favorites9[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites9[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites9[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "food":
                        if(favorites10[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites10[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites10[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "nature":
                        if(favorites11[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites11[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites11[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "places":
                        if(favorites12[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites12[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites12[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "transportation":
                        if(favorites13[i1-1].equals("true")){
                            favorites13[i1-1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites13[i1-1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }


                saveArray(favorites1,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites2,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites3,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites4,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites5,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites6,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites7,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites8,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites9,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites10,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites11,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites12,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites13,"favorites1",Pun.this);

            }
        });

        switch (MainActivity.category) {
            case "body":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPath);

                System.out.print(i1);

                if(favorites1[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "crime":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mCrimePath);
                if(favorites2[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "entertainment":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mEntertaintmentPath);
                if(favorites3[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "health":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mHealthPath);
                if(favorites4[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "people":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPeoplePath);
                if(favorites5[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "technology":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mTechnologyPath);
                if(favorites6[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "work":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mWorkPath);
                if(favorites7[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "business":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mBusinessPath);
                if(favorites8[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "education":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mEducationPath);
                if(favorites9[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "food":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mFoodPath);
                if(favorites10[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "nature":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mNaturePath);
                if(favorites11[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "places":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPlacesPath);
                if(favorites12[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            case "transportation":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mTransportationPath);
                if(favorites13[i1-1].equals("true"))
                    favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random r = new Random();
                int i1 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;

                textView.setText(mLines.get(i1));

                counter++;
                if (counter == 3) {
                    counter = 0;
                    // ad
                    displayInterstitial();
                }

                switch (MainActivity.category) {
                    case "body":
                    if (favorites1[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                        favorites1[i1 - 1] = "false";
                        favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                    } else {
                        favorites1[i1 - 1] = "true";
                        favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                    }
                    break;
                    case "crime":
                        if (favorites2[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites2[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites2[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "entertainment":
                        if (favorites3[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites3[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites3[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "health":
                        if (favorites4[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites4[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites4[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "people":
                        if (favorites5[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites5[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites5[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "technology":
                        if (favorites6[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites6[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites6[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "work":
                        if (favorites7[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites7[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites7[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "business":
                        if (favorites8[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites8[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites8[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "education":
                        if (favorites9[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites9[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites9[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "food":
                        if (favorites10[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites10[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites10[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "nature":
                        if (favorites11[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites11[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites11[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "places":
                        if (favorites12[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites12[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites12[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "transportation":
                        if (favorites13[i1 - 1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites13[i1 - 1] = "false";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites13[i1 - 1] = "true";
                            favoritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                saveArray(favorites1,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites2,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites3,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites4,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites5,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites6,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites7,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites8,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites9,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites10,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites11,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites12,"favorites1",Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites13,"favorites1",Pun.this);
            }
        });


    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
        int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
        String array[] = new String[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);
        return array;
    }
}
```

It seems to be occuring at this part:

```
if(favorites1[i1-1].equals("true"))
```

Here are the load and save methods:

```
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
        int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
        String array[] = new String[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);
        return array;
    }
```

NOTE ^ the above methods work fine. My application ran correctly with one favorites array, but when I added more it started crashing. I must be missing something simple, but I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array initializations are always being overwritten by the returns from `loadArray()`. But if there wasn't an array saved with the name passed to `loadArray()`, it returns an empty array. Then when you try to access an element of that array it will give an out-of-bounds exception. Try running your load operations first, and then do your "false" initialization only if there was not data loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that makes sense! What's the best way to check? Would it be checking for nil values for each array element?

Comment: @User That's up to you. You might check for 0 size, or null data, or you could modify `loadArray()` to better detect when there's nothing saved and return a null array instead of an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using a String[] and start using ArrayList instead, this way you can add elements until your heart is content, and you won't have to manage which String[] you are using.

Here is a code snippet that should get you started:

```
List<String> favorites = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then to add an element:

```
favorites.add(myFavorite);
```

To get an element:

```
favorites.get(elementId);
```

Or you can use a Map key-value pair:

```
Map<String,String> favorites = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

where the first String is the key you want to save, and the second String is the Value, and in your case the value would be the category you are sorting the favorites on. To add a value:

```
favorites.put("http://thiscool.link", "sports");
```

To iterate over the Map:

```
String desiredKey = "sports";
for(String key : favorites.keyMap()){
     if(desiredKey.equals(favorites.get(key)){
         return key;
     }
}
```

Since all keys to the Map are unique.